# How to run DISM against a local source?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, dism

How can I run DISM agaisnt a USB Windows installer to repair my local Windows files?

This is what I tried in Windows 8.1:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

It returns error 0x800f081f:

[image]

Note that my WinSxS folder has several folders and sizes 6.88 GB, however DISM won't detect it.

I understand that a healthy source can be a Windows USB Installer.

How can I do this?

Comment: `/restorehealth` is not about detecting `%WinDir%\WinSxS`, but about verifying the system file backups within it against known good sources, preferably via Windows Update (which is why this requires an internet connection), or as a last resort, an `install.wim`/`install.esd`. _The Component Store [WinSxS] should never be entered into or modified by a user._  Once `DISM` has verified there's no corruption in WinSxS, `SFC` can then be utilized to compare the system files within `%WinDir%` against the known good copies contained within the Component Store [WinSxS] and replace them as necessary.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can point to  the WIM file of the Windows 8.1 RTM DVD:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess
```

(where D: is your Windows DVD drive or mounted Win8.1 ISO)

Comment: Thank you, the Windows 8.1 RTM DVD released in December did include the necessary install.wim.