# How can I repair my component store in Windows 8.1 with a downloaded image using dism.exe?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, dism, sfc

I'm running Windows 8.1 and I get the following error when I try to repair my system:

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth /logpath:D:\Downloads\dismlog.txt

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 14098

The component store has been corrupted.

The DISM log file can be found at D:\Downloads\dismlog.txt
```

The relevant portion of the log is:

```
2015-04-03 14:19:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=7088  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x80073712) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
```

There's a lot of information in the CBS log but I'm not sure what is relevant. [Here is the CBS log.](http://pastebin.com/k18zJ6NN)

A repair based on booting the USB image of Windows 8.1 downloaded from MS failed. Windows update failed. It seems like I should be able to fix the component store using the image, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: /scanhealth only scans, you need to run **/RestoreHealth**

Comment: It returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the syntax for PowerShell is the following:

```
Repair-WindowsImage -Online -RestoreHealth -Source G:\sources\install.wim:1
```

Note that I still get an error back about corruption, but this is what I was looking for. The iso download from Microsoft didn't have a wim file, but I did use a free program to convert install.esd to install.wim.

Comment: I've posted the DISM command here: http://superuser.com/a/870956/174557