# What is adcjavas?

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview

Recently, a strange file came up during one of my regular DISMs, `adcjavas.inc`.

The only place I can seem to find it is in my `C:\Windows\WinSxS\` directory, but that doesn't really give me too many clues as to what this file is or what it does.

What is this file, and should I be worrying that it's corrupt?

---

Windows 10 build 10159

Comment: I opened the file and I see this: **ADO constants include file for JavaScript** What do you see if you run DISM (http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) to fix it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Mismatched hashes. Opening the file gives me lots of null bits.

Comment: use DISM to point to the WIM on the ISO: http://superuser.com/a/870956/174557

Comment: also update to Build 10162

Comment: @magicandre1981: Managed to fix it by copying the AMD64 file to the x86 dir (and fixing permissions), but I'm still confused as to why I need what looks like an IIS file on a regular PC. However, I am downloading 10162 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is adcjavas.inc?

This file contains ADO constants that are used for client side scripting with Microsoft JScript.

> Microsoft JScript does not support type libraries, so you do not need
> to reference ADO in your project. Consequently, no associated features
> such as command line completion are supported. Also, by default, ADO
> enumerated constants are not defined in JScript.
>
> However, ADO provides you with two include files containing the
> following definitions to be used with JScript:
>
> - For server-side scripting use Adojavas.inc, which is installed in the c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\ folder by default.
> - For client-side scripting use Adcjavas.inc, which is installed in the c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\msdac\ folder by default.

Source [JScript ADO Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj249002.aspx#sectionSection1)