# Why is SFC /scannow Corrupt and CHKDSK gave error 0x800f081f?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, chkdsk

I've tried to run `sfc /scannow` 3 times and restart between them, but it's not solved by that way.

I've tried `CHKDSK` too but it still error.

Also, I've tried `CHKDSK` with the online but cant fix them.

[image: please fix]

here are the rar files
[rar](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1751D174B4F27F0B!484&authkey=!AA9jTl2FL0MmlKQ&ithint=file%2Crar)

here are the `CHKDSK` with source screenshoot
[SCREENSHOOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdMyk.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Have you reviewed either of the logs listed in the image for more information?

Comment: What errors did CHKDSK report?  I ask because you've said CHKDSK returns error 0x800f081f, yet your screenshot shows it's DISM that's returning the error.  What happens if you do what it suggests and [provide a Source for DISM](http://superuser.com/a/870956/23133) to pull files from?

Comment: copy the folder C:\windows\logs\CBS and DISM to your desktop, compress both folders into 1 ZIP/RAR file, upload the zip to Onedrive and post a share link here

Comment: CharlieBB --> i reviewed but i can't understand how to fix them sir. Techie007 --> looks update txt
magicandre --> looks update rar

Comment: TECHIE007 -->
here is the note files

 https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1751D174B4F27F0B!485&authkey=!AL_YX9Xh2p1h36U&ithint=file%2Clog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the log files, several RTM files are damaged and Windows Update fails to get them `CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING_FROM_WU_CAB`.

```
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_microsoft-windows-p..log.appxmain.deploy_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_198fbefebe778838
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_microsoft-windows-dims.log_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_086ed23a71609d35
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_microsoft-windows-s..logon-firewallrules_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_28442fcea4813d17
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_microsoft-windows-dims-keyroam.log_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_3ef6becfb6f272e6
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_microsoft-windows-dims-autoenroll.log_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_1db33251da993cd5
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_microsoft-windows-i..logginglibraries-gc_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_ca0080af74a0038b
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            wow64_microsoft-windows-i..logginglibraries-gc_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_d4552b01a900c586
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_wcf-system.io.log_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.10240.16384_none_60c812391bb5775e
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            msil_system.io.log_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.10240.16384_none_5304c2599556e122
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            x86_wcf-system.io.log_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.10240.16384_none_a87549103031a064
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_microsoft-windows-p..log.appxmain.deploy_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_3049138d5feb9afe
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_netfx4-system.io.log_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.10240.16384_none_ebc8ed700fbf0f0e
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            msil_system.io.log_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.10240.16384_none_dc7fbbfd30edbd4b
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            x86_microsoft-windows-dims-autoenroll.log_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_c19496ce223bcb9f
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            x86_microsoft-windows-dims.log_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_ac5036b6b9032bff
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            x86_microsoft-windows-dims-keyroam.log_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_e2d8234bfe9501b0
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_microsoft-windows-o..logonanim.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_en-us_4450d86b0e610ae1
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            amd64_netfx4-system.io.log.resources_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.10240.16384_en-us_195437fd2efa9aeb
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            msil_system.io.log.resources_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.10240.16384_en-us_fceb16c2b61fda84
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt            msil_system.io.log.resources_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.10240.16384_en-us_73701d1f1a88fe5b
Repair failed: Missing replacement manifest.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-mapcontrol_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_1b558da4a5404873\resource.db
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.

Summary:
Operation: Detect and Repair 
Operation result: 0x800f081f
Last Successful Step: Entire operation completes.
Total Detected Corruption:  21
    CBS Manifest Corruption:    0
    CBS Metadata Corruption:    0
    CSI Manifest Corruption:    20
    CSI Metadata Corruption:    0
    CSI Payload Corruption: 1
Total Repaired Corruption:  0
    CBS Manifest Repaired:  0
    CSI Manifest Repaired:  0
    CSI Payload Repaired:   0
    CSI Store Metadata refreshed:   True
```

Get a Windows 10 Th1 Build 10240 ISO, mount the ISO and run this DISM command:

> Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
>   /source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess

*(where D is the virtual DVD drive)*

Comment: ok, i'll try, but it means that my windows 10 installed not from that build, so, my question is, can i repair my build of windows 10 with the windows 10 th1 build 10240 that you command for ?

Comment: according to the pictures you use that build. Nice to hear that it worked :)