# Win 10: Dism /RestoreHealth fails: "The remote procedure call failed."

Tags: windows, windows-10, dism

I ran `sfc /scannow` from Command Prompt with administrator privileges, but the system could not repair itself, even after rebooting. I tried to repair the Windows Store using the Windows 10 install image using†

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:E:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess
```

but that fails with error message "Error 1726 The remote procedure call failed." Running these commands in safe mode makes no difference. Please help.

---

Here is a screenshot of the above process and error [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrGKr.png] , the [dism.log](http://textuploader.com/5ejba) file, the [CBS.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0muykepb73ux3zs/CBS.log?dl=1) file, and [a list of system services which I have disabled](http://textuploader.com/5ejbd) (as compared to default).

† - *See [Windows cant repair even with sfc /scannow](https://superuser.com/questions/755680/windows-cant-repair-even-with-sfc-scannow/755684#755684) and [How to run DISM against a local source?](https://superuser.com/questions/870864/how-to-run-dism-against-a-local-source)*

Comment: Why exactly do you believe you need to run these commands?

Comment: Where did the install.wim come from exactly?  I have a very vague memory that using `install.wim:1` does something very specific and where a different value then `1 ` does something else.  Which is the reason I ask these questions

Comment: I assume, the RPC services on this virtual machine, are set to be available? The following is contained within, Winerror.h, **`#define RPC_S_CALL_FAILED                1726L`**.  What likely is happening is there is a lock, on a file, that is blocking the scan from happening.  You can determine what that file is with a tool like Process Explorer. The cbs.log will contain, `Unable to move file to pendingDeletes. Filename ......", if that is the case.

Comment: @Ramhound, A1: I can't get the .NET 3.5 Framework to install no matter what I do (which I'll save for a separate thread) and attempted `sfc /scannow` to attempt to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Ramhound, A2: I'm using an ISO of Windows 10 Pro (Win10_1511_2_English_x64.iso), which I downloaded from Microsoft.com a few weeks ago. I'm not sure about the `install.wim:1`. I just copied from the second referenced SuperUser answer.

Comment: What about CBS.log does it indicate a file lock condition?

Comment: @Ramhound, A3i: Remote Procedure Call (RPC) services is set to Automatic and is running. Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locater service is set to Manual.

Comment: @Ramhound, A3ii: I don't see anything indicating a locked file in the CBS.log file, but uploaded it so you can check.

Comment: Does anything different happen if you use `Dism /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`?

Comment: @Ben N: `Dism /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` works successfully, but both prior problems still persist.