# Dism Restore Image Health fails with Error 1910

Tags: command-line, dism, error-logging

I am trying to restore online image health using Dism command, however I seem not to be successful. This error is persisting.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:G:\Sources\install.esd\Install.esd

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0


Error: 1910

The object exporter specified was not found.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

How do I resolve this error?

**Please note I have already enable Remote Proceedure Call services**.

**Update 1:**

Revised my commands (as suggested in comments) as shown below but still got the same error.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:G:\Sources\install.esd

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0


Error: 1910

The object exporter specified was not found.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:G:\Sources\install.esd

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0


Error: 1910

The object exporter specified was not found.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I then extracted part of the error log, particularly where I noted many errors, see below:

```
2017-04-03 10:10:38, Warning               DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11096 TID=7996 CBS AddSource failed with HRESULT=0x80070776! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2017-04-03 10:10:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11096 TID=7996 CBS session options=0x40100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2017-04-03 10:10:38, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11096 TID=7996 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80070776)
2017-04-03 10:10:38, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11096 TID=7996 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x80070776)
2017-04-03 10:10:38, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11096 TID=7996 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x80070776)
2017-04-03 10:10:38, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11096 TID=7996 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80070776)
2017-04-03 10:10:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11096 TID=7996 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
```

**Update 2**

I tried **all** suggestions in comments section without success.

Other things I did:

- Since I thought .esd file was the culprit, I used command line to convert esd file to .wim and remounted.
- File system checker found no intergrity violations
- `Chkdsk` no problem

**Update 3**

As suggested in comments I have uploaded the dism error log after using wim:

```
Warning               DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9284 TID=14132 CBS AddSource failed with HRESULT=0x80070776! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
```

cbs error log:

```
Info                  CBS    Failed to GetFile from WIM sandbox process [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Error                 CBS    Failed to look for file Servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-MediaCenter-Package-avcore~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.3.9600.16384.mum in some alternate sources [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Info                  CBS    Failed to GetFile from WIM sandbox process [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Error                 CBS    Failed to look for file Servicing\Packages\update.mum in some alternate sources [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Info                  CBS    Repr: Not able to find replacement manifests for package Microsoft-Windows-MediaCenter-Package-avcore~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.3.9600.16384 from any local source
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Info                  CBS    Failed to GetFile from WIM sandbox process [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Error                 CBS    Failed to look for file Servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-MediaCenter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.3.9600.16384.mum in some alternate sources [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Info                  CBS    Failed to GetFile from WIM sandbox process [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Error                 CBS    Failed to look for file Servicing\Packages\update.mum in some alternate sources [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Info                  CBS    Repr: Not able to find replacement manifests for package Microsoft-Windows-MediaCenter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.3.9600.16384 from any local source
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Info                  CBS    ASSERT: Assertion failed in onecore\base\cbs\util\inc\CbsArray.h(535)
Index out of bound.
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Info                  CBS    Failed to FinalizeEx using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800706be]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to unmarshall worker stream [HRESULT = 0x80070776 - ]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to unmarshall worker stream [HRESULT = 0x80070776]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to get worker process. [HRESULT = 0x80070776]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to create worker session. [HRESULT = 0x80070776]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to get worker session. [HRESULT = 0x80070776]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to unmarshall worker stream [HRESULT = 0x80070776 - ]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to unmarshall worker stream [HRESULT = 0x80070776]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to get worker process. [HRESULT = 0x80070776]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to create worker session. [HRESULT = 0x80070776]
2017-04-04 11:11:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to get worker session. [HRESULT = 0x80070776]
```

The problem still persists, is there any other workarounds to solve this issue?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 education 64bit (see image version in question)

Comment: So what errors are in the log file?

Comment: @DavidPostill Nothing substantial, nevertheless let me append them in my question. The log is pretty big couldn't upload it either :(

Comment: I haven't used ESD files much but don't you have to specify the source is an ESD? "/Source:esd:G:\Sources\install.esd\Install.esd" otherwise, it probably thinks its an oddly named WIM.

Comment: You seem to have specified `\install.esd` twice. Is that by accident?

Comment: @CConard96 I tried your workaround but its still shows the same error

Comment: @FleetCommand Might have been a mistake, however I changed to single install.esd but the same error persists. Let me put the screenshot in the question

Comment: use [1607 ISO with a install.wim](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), not a ESD and [point to this WIM with DISM](https://superuser.com/a/870956/174557)

Comment: share the DISM and CBS logs after trying to use the WIM

Comment: @magicandre1981, I have added the logs you requested.

Comment: I reckon this needs a repair install, and for the umpteenth time, I am forced to do such annoying repairs. I am going to ditch windows for this, besides I been using linux for a while

Comment: 6.3.9600.16384 is Windows 8.1, but I think you talk about Windows 10. I'm confused ...

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry I am not following? I use Windows 10 education as shown above image version is 10.0.14393. I never talked about windows 8. I just uploaded the error logs as you suggested. What you referring to are just dism packages I unistalled long back it was media centre for win 8. otherwise I use windows 10

Comment: your last edit talsk about 8.1: **Repr: Not able to find replacement manifests for package Microsoft-Windows-MediaCenter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.3.9600.16384 from any local source
2017-04-04 10:44:58, Info                  CBS    ASSERT: Assertion failed in onecore\base\cbs\util\inc\CbsArray.h(535)
Index out of bound.**

Comment: @magicandre1981 maybe thats what is corrupting the whole dism restore health commands thats why I need to get past this mess. perhaps a repair install is the only option.

Comment: have you updated from 8.1 to 10 (july 2015), next to november 2015 version of win10 till now to the JUly 2016 version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56546/discussion-between-xavier-fakerat-and-magicandre1981).

Comment: best is to do a clean install with 1703 ISO

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks I had no option but to perform a repair install with the ISO

Comment: ok, post this as answer and accept the answer later